# How to do deployment to gke kubernetes on self hosted agent windows 10?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an azure release pipeline on my self hosted computer. I can run kubectl command on my local machine.

[image]

when it runs the `kubectl apply` step of release, it throws exception.

```
2023-03-07T05:57:28.6055463Z ==============================================================================
2023-03-07T05:57:28.6056482Z Task         : Kubectl
2023-03-07T05:57:28.6057456Z Description  : Deploy, configure, update a Kubernetes cluster in Azure Container Service by running kubectl commands
2023-03-07T05:57:28.6058070Z Version      : 0.216.0
2023-03-07T05:57:28.6058624Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-03-07T05:57:28.6059197Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/kubernetes
2023-03-07T05:57:28.6060090Z ==============================================================================
2023-03-07T05:57:29.4681708Z [command]C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\kubectl.exe --kubeconfig C:\agent-demos\_work\_temp\kubectlTask\1678168649409\config apply -n default -f C:\agent-demos\_work\r1\a\_app-web-ui\k8s-deployment.yml
2023-03-07T05:57:29.6838186Z Unable to connect to the server: getting credentials: exec: executable gke-gcloud-auth-plugin.exe not found
2023-03-07T05:57:29.6839030Z 
2023-03-07T05:57:29.6839663Z It looks like you are trying to use a client-go credential plugin that is not installed.
2023-03-07T05:57:29.6840006Z 
2023-03-07T05:57:29.6840458Z To learn more about this feature, consult the documentation available at:
2023-03-07T05:57:29.6841141Z       https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#client-go-credential-plugins
2023-03-07T05:57:29.6841504Z 
2023-03-07T05:57:29.6842121Z Install gke-gcloud-auth-plugin for use with kubectl by following https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke
2023-03-07T05:57:29.7040543Z ##[error]The process 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\kubectl.exe' failed with exit code 1
```

I have installed `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin` but did not work.

I run the command on local machine:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials CLUSTER_NAME
```

and it returned:

```
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
kubeconfig entry generated for gisarts.
```

I applied the [kubectl auth changes](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke), but did not work.

How can I fix this? Is self hosted agent runs as local system user?

Comment: Did you check this? https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke

Comment: yes I did all of them and updated the post.

Comment: Did you try using some other task like [Kubernetes@0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/kubernetes-manifest-v0?view=azure-pipelines)?

Comment: Hi, gke-gcloud-outh-plugin executable path  is running in Azure release pipeline  and Azure release pipeline has access to the GKE cluster; as you are using local system try running agent with a different user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed kubectl or gcloud cli by windows user '`someuser`', Azure self hosted agent shoud use this user. So open the services in windows os. And find the agent service named '`Azure Pipelines Agent (organization.project)`' and double click it. Opened window has a tab named `Log On` and select This Account radio button to type `someuser` and `password`. This allows azure agent to do your build and deployments.